# Iterate over table using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I want to get data from a website which is in table. First i try to get the whole table and then get the `tr`'s and `td`'s that are inside it. The code i have now just return empty array.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function run() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(
    "https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2021_standings.html" //Eastern Conference
  );

  var temp = [];
  const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const tableBody = document.querySelector(
      'table[id="confs_standings_E"] tbody'
    );

     for (var i = 0; i < tableBody.length; i++) {
      const tr = tableBody[i].querySelectorAll("tr");
      for (var j = 0; j < tr.length; j++) {
       const td = tr[j].querySelectorAll("td").innerText;
       temp.push(td);
  }
}
  });

  console.log(temp);
  //await browser.close();
}

run();
```

UPDATE

I tried the solution that was posted and it worked so thanks for that but i wanted to try to get solution in another way. The code below gets the right number of elements, but they are all `undefined`
This is what i get in console:

```
0: (7) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
1: (7) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
2: (7) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
3: (7) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
4: (7) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
5: (7) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
6: (7) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
7: (7) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
8: (7) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
9: (7) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
10: (7) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
11: (7) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
12: (7) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
13: (7) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
14: (7) [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

And here is new code:

```
async function run() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(
    "https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2021_standings.html" //Eastern Conference
  );

  seznamEkip = [];
  const ekipe = await page.$$("#confs_standings_E tbody tr");

  for (const ekipa of ekipe) {
    const podatki = await ekipa.$$("td");
    const spread = [...podatki].map((element) => element.innerText);
    seznamEkip.push(spread);
  }

  console.log(seznamEkip);
}

run();
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Recall that [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns a single element, not an array. Therefore, iterating over its length with a for-loop does not make sense, since it does not have a length -- it's just an element. You may find it useful to iterate over the [element's `.children` instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children).

As an alternative, consider utilizing `querySelectorAll` and utilizing a slightly different selector instead. For instance, this will select every td in the tbody, and return an array of their `innerText`s:

```js
const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const tableBody = document.querySelectorAll('#confs_standings_E tbody td');
    return Array.from(tableBody).map(element => element.innerText);
});
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your solution worked, but i also tried to find some other way to solve this and i updated my question with new code and new problem so if u know how to solve it i would appreciate it.

Comment: Regarding your update, note that the [`page.$$` method](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.0.0&show=api-pageselector-1) returns a Promise that resolves to an array of Puppeteer [ElementHandles](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.0.0&show=api-class-elementhandle), not actual DOM elements. Thus, `innerText` is not defined. You should use Puppeteer APIs to access the text by evaluating JS on the page. Check out the [`ElementHandle.$$eval` method](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.0.0&show=api-elementhandleevalselector-pagefunction-args) as a start.